# Unified style sharing buttons

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I'm looking for a library providing the three main social media sharing buttons in a unified style, a little like the following image:

[image]

Are there (GitHub?) projects providing out-of-box unified social media buttons?

Comment: Have you tried Google'ing this, there are lots out there... http://mashable.com/2011/03/11/add-social-sharing-buttons/

Comment: @tim.baker: Yes, I've tried Googling. The solutions in the link don't fit the attached image.

Comment: I would suspect that those are created specifically in house for which ever site they are off, out of interest what site are they off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sapegin.github.com/social-likes/ — this plugin providing social buttons in unified style. It is not exact the same style as on the image, but it can be easily customized.